# Issue with avstract java class paramaeter

Tags: java, parameters

The following code is the solution code, which declares an abstract class with one absract subclass (that in turn has two subclasses) and another subclass. Because the method setScore() has to be implemented in three different ways, and the objecttype differs for each case, I'm presuming we use the parameter P to define it.

```
public abstract class Vak<P> implements EvaluatieSpecificatie, 
Comparable<Vak> {


private VakInfo vak;    

public abstract void setScore(P parameter);


public Vak(VakInfo v) {
    vak = v;
}

public String getVakNaam() {
    return vak.getNaam();
}

public int getStudiepunten() {
    return vak.getStudiepunten();
}

public String getVakcode() {
    return vak.getVakcode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(vak);
    if (isGeslaagd()) {
        sb.append(" C");
    } else {
        sb.append(" niet geslaagd - moet hernomen worden");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Vak v) {
    // sorteren van vakken op basis van studiepunten
    // this < v --> neg waarde teruggeven
    // this > v --> pos waarde teruggeven
    // this = v --> 0 teruggeven
    return this.getStudiepunten() - v.getStudiepunten();
}
}
```

Now, what I don't understand is how exactly this class ClassName"<"Parameter">" thing works, when to use it, or what exactly its called. I've tried to look it up, but I can't seem to find any information on it. Could anyone explain to me what exactly this is, and how/when it's supposed to be used? (Or link me in the right direction), perhaps by giving a simple example (since I'm not sure if asking for code is required).

I'm terribly sorry if this question isn't appropriate, but I'd really like to understand, so here goes.

Comment: You might want to look at Java Generics but I am sure someone will give proper answer

Comment: What is `this class ClassName thing`?

Comment: What do you exactly want to know? what class P is? Then You can use `instanceof` expression like `if (view instanceof EditText)`

Comment: @A.Sharma Sorry, the "<"parameter">" dissapeared because it was between tags. So I'm talking about adding "<"parameter">" to a regular class declaration.

Comment: @MaximBerezovsky What exactly the parameter type is that is used to create an abstract method without specifying the objecttype.

Comment: have you read about generic types? try this for instance:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

Appereantly it's called a generic type. Thank you @HRgiger.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html